# Atom material icon not working in WebStorm

Tags: icons, webstorm

I installed Atom Material icon plugin in WebStorm 2021.1.3.

When I write `index.html` the icon does not show it, but when I change the name before `.html` (e.g. `othername.html`) it displays the icon.

How do I display an icon for `index.html`?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is due to a defect in the icon file, which you can see in the following link:

```
https://material-theme.com/docs/reference/associations/#index
```

To solve this problem, you must enter the following path: **File > Settings > atom material icons settings**

Other items are available in the photo :

[image: The first part]

[image: Part two]

[image: third part]

Rename the icon name from **index** to **indx**

Note that the index name must be changed in the settings section so that the icons are displayed correctly. This was the solution I was able to solve my problem. Good luck

Comment: This should be the accepted solution! This worked for me in the new Ultimate UI as well.

Comment: Thank you, changes have been made in the new version, but as you said, this is the only solution.
I hope the Atom material team will solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, the file type of `index.html` was changed to *Auto-detect file type by context* or *Text*. You can change it in the settings: *Preferences / Settings | Editor | File Types*, find *Auto-detect file type by context* or *Text* and delete `index.html` from File name patterns list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. File name patterns list it was empty !